# Display selected item on checkbox on the next activity

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, checkbox

I have a listview using checkbox and a Submit button on the same layout.

Right now I can only click on the checkbox and it does not do anything. I read a lot of tutorials on displaying the items but most of them comes out as a toast message. **What I want is for the items to be displayed in a new activity when I click the Submit button.**

This is the code for the `CheckBoxListAdapter`:

```
public class CheckboxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private LayoutInflater inflator;

private List<SampleData> dataList;

public CheckboxListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflator) {
    super();
    this.inflator = inflator;

    dataList = new ArrayList<SampleData>();

    dataList.add(new SampleData("Teh Ais (130 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Teh O Ais (130 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Neslo Ais (170 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Kopi Ais (130 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Kopi O Ais (130 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Jus buah (130 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Limau ais (40 cal)", false));
    dataList.add(new SampleData("Air berkarbonat (120 cal)", false));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.element_example, null);

        view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    SampleData data = (SampleData) getItem(position);

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb.setChecked(data.isSelected());
    cb.setTag(data);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(data.getName());

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    SampleData data = (SampleData) view.getTag();
    data.setSelected(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
}

}
```

The code for the `CheckboxListActivity`:

```
public class CheckboxListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);

    CheckboxListAdapter adapter = new CheckboxListAdapter(
            getLayoutInflater());

    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

The `SampleData.java`:

```
public class SampleData {

private String name;

private boolean selected;

public SampleData(String name, boolean selected) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

}
```

The first XML for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="389dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.79" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The second XML for the checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the selected item on an Intent object as you start the next activity. Retrieve the selected item from the intent in the next Activity and use it.

Example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Selected_Item", selectedItemData);
startActivity(intent)
```

In the next Activity do the following

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String selectedItem = intent.getStringExtra("Selected_Item")
```

Comment: could you explain in detail about this? I'm sorry if I sound dumb, I had been going through a lot of codes for the past 15 hours.

Comment: Get the selected value in current activity. When you are ready to start next activity, start the activity with Intent and extra data which is the selected value. And when next activity starts, in onCreate retrieve the selected value as I showed from the intent. And do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I've used intent before but it was for an EditText and TextView. Since the button will be put in the CheckboxListActivity, the intent will be under the onclick method of the button but referring to my code, selected_item refers to SampleData?

Comment: SampleData is just a string and a boolean. Using the code above you can store a string and send it to the next activity. It shouldn't be hard from there how to figure out how to send the boolean as well. Then you can reconstruct the object in your new activity.